# MySQL statement to save password to Database?

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

I have an SQL statement that saves a username into a MySQL database on phpmyadmin that works like a charm:

> ```
> Dim SQLStatement As String = "INSERT INTO accountinfodb(`Usernames`) VALUES ('" & txtUsername.Text & "')"
> ```

## However

I also ask for the users password, which I'd like to store as well, so I though this would make sense:

```
Dim SQLStatement As String = "INSERT INTO accountinfodb(`Usernames`, `Passwords`) VALUES ('" & txtUsername.Text & txtPasswd.Text & "')"
```

Unfortunately this code does not work, I get errors about a valid and open connection, or a syntax error in my MySQL syntax. So I was wondering if anyone knew the correct way to store the username and password into my DB?

Here is my FULL vb.net code.

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient


Public Class frmSignup
Dim ServerString As String = "Server=localhost;User Id=root;Password=;Database=accountinfo"
Dim SQLConnection As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection

Private Sub Form3_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    SQLConnection.ConnectionString = ServerString

    Try
        If SQLConnection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            SQLConnection.Open()
            MsgBox("Successfully connected to DB")

        Else
            SQLConnection.Close()
            MsgBox("Failed to connect to DB")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)

    End Try
End Sub

Public Sub SaveAccountInformation(ByRef SQLStatement As String)
    Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand

    With cmd
        .CommandText = SQLStatement
        .CommandType = CommandType.Text
        .Connection = SQLConnection
        .ExecuteNonQuery()
    End With
    SQLConnection.Close()
    SQLConnection.Dispose()
End Sub

Private Sub btnSignup_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSignup.Click
    If txtPasswd.Text = txtPasswd2.Text Then
        MessageBox.Show("Passwords Match!")

        Dim SQLStatement As String = "INSERT INTO accountinfodb(`Usernames`, `Passwords`) VALUES ('" & txtUsername.Text & txtPasswd.Text & "')"
        SaveAccountInformation(SQLStatement)



        MessageBox.Show("Account Successfully Registered")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Passwords Do Not Match!")
        txtPasswd.Text = Focus()
        txtPasswd.Clear()
        txtPasswd2.Text = Focus()
        txtPasswd2.Clear()

    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

## EDIT 1

@Rahul

I added your SQL Statement to my code and I am given the following error when I input a random username/passwd

> An unhandled exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException'
>   occurred in MySql.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'test')' at line 1

Comment: google for sql statements with parameters for many reasons

Comment: @SirRufo Can you at least explain why my SQL Statement does not work?

Comment: You promise the DB 2 items, then glue the two items together and only send one; thats the syntax error.  Use SQL Parameters and what you are doing is much clearer (and it wont crash if the user name is `D'Angelo`...or worse). You dont open the connection so that is the other error

Comment: @Plutonix But is the connection not opened via SQLConnection.Open()? I can confirm that the DB is connected because my usernames get saved, it's just the passwords that don't? Unless it's some freak coincidence that the SQL server SHOULDN'T be open but somehow manages to?

Comment: If NET says there is not valid, open connection, then there must not be.  There is no need to open it when the form loads (you dont do anything with it til later).  Create and open it then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your SQL `INSERT` statement, it's missing a `,` comma in `VALUES` section

```
VALUES ('" & txtUsername.Text & txtPasswd.Text & "')
                             ^... Here
```

Your statement should look like

```
"INSERT INTO accountinfodb(`Usernames`, `Passwords`) 
VALUES ('" & txtUsername.Text & "','" & txtPasswd.Text & "')"
```

**Edit:**
I must mentioned that your current code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attack due to the fact that you are passing user input directly as  concatenated values. You should rather use `SqlParameter` and pass those values as parameter instead accordingly. A sample would be

```
Dim SQLStatement As String = "INSERT INTO accountinfodb(`Usernames`, `Passwords`) VALUES (@username, @password)"

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtUsername.Text.Trim())
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtPasswd.Text.Trim())
```

Comment: I would say is missing a field then a comma :-)

Comment: And missing strategic quotes

Comment: @Steve Can you explain? :)

Comment: Two fields 'username' and 'password', one value _txtUsername.Text & txtPasswd.Text_  the & concatenates together the two textboxes values

Comment: @Jcrow, see edit in answer, should be fine now. You were passing a single value whereas mentioned 2 columns in your statement.

Comment: @Rahul Check the OP, I receive an error when trying your SQL Statement.

Comment: @Jcrow, yes there was a missing `'` single quote. See edit again.

Comment: @Rahul Thank you very much for your patience, I have marked your answer as helpful!

Comment: @Rahul I think you should add at least a warning about the inherent dangers of using this code. It works now but it is a disaster waiting to happen